# Not able to go back to previous page while using Router in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I am new to Reactjs.So I am making a basic website where there will be a link to **Home page**, a link to **privacy policy** and a link to **Terms and conditions**.
Below is the code for App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import PrivacyPolicy from './components/PrivacyPolicy';
import TermsAndConditions from './components/TermsAndConditions';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Header from './components/Header';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/privacy-policy">PrivacyPolicy</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/terms-and-conditions">TermsAndConditions</Link>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}

        <Switch>

          <Route path="/privacy-policy">
            <PrivacyPolicy />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/terms-and-conditions">
            <TermsAndConditions />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
    <Footer/>
    </div>
  );

}

export default App;
```

Below is the code for **Privacy Policy** page that is privacypolicy.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function PrivacyPolicy() {

    const element =  (
        <div style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <span>{"some text"}</span>
        </div>
    );
    ReactDOM.render(element,document.getElementById('root'));
}

export default PrivacyPolicy;
```

Now The code for Terms and conditions page

```
import React from 'react';

function TermsAndConditions() {
    return (
        <div style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <span>{"some text."}</span>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TermsAndConditions;
```

Now the problem is whenever I go to privacy policy page by clicking on the link on home page I am able to go to privacy policy page and now when press the back button in chrome the link changes to home page but the page is not refreshed it is still showing the privacy policy content while in case of terms and conditions I am able to come back.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Update your Privacy Policy to:

```
import React from 'react';


function PrivacyPolicy() {
    return (
        <div style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <span>{"some text"}</span>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PrivacyPolicy;
```

Comment: ohh so sorry I should have mentioned that. Actually Whenever I am clicking on the privacy policy link it is getting rendered on the same page (home page) . I want it to be rendered on other page.

Comment: in simple words whenever I am clicking privacy policy link the text in privacy policy page is rendered on the same page below the three links I want it to be rendered in a whole new page